# AddForce not moving imported model in Unity

Tags: unity, physics, movement

I've got a Unity project with an imported .fbx model I'm attempting to add movement to.

As a test, I've added a sphere primitive with a sphere collider, a rigid body, and the following script:

```
public class ball_test : MonoBehaviour {

  private Rigidbody rb;

  void Start ()
    {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

  void FixedUpdate ()
    {
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (1f, 0.0f, 1f);

    rb.AddForce (movement);
    }
  }
```

This is partly copied from the Roll A Ball tutorial, and this works fine.  The ball slowly rolls with no problem.

I've imported a custom model, added a box collider, a rigid body, and assigned to it the same script.  **It doesn't move.**

Here's how they're set up:

[image: Sphere]
[image: Car]

Comment: This seems like a problem with friction. Try to make a [Physic material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) with Zero friction and set it in the Collider component.

Comment: @AdityaYadav, No change.

Comment: Have you tried just cranking up the force? It's harder to slide a crate than roll a wheel. ;)

Comment: @DMGregory, yep, that was it.

Comment: Cool. Maybe share the force values you needed to use as an answer so future users can get a sense of how much they need to crank it up in similar situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here had to do with the sphere collider versus the box collider.  I didn't realize the physics engine was taking the shape of the object into consideration.

**The box requires a lot more force to move than the sphere.**

I had to increase the force on the custom model to at least 6f before I saw any movement, where as 1f was fine for the ball.

**There was also too much friction with the ground.**

I had to apply a zero friction physic material to the model's box collider.  Without this, the car would move at 10f, but just roll over end-to-end instead of sliding/driving.